# Cloud Dataflow: a lookup table that is updated every hour as a side input

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Using Apache Beam on Cloud Dataflow, I want to use a lookup table that updates every hour.

I found a solution for slowly-changing lookup cache [here](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/guide-to-common-cloud-dataflow-use-case-patterns-part-1), but the article specifically says the pattern is appropriate for daily, rather than hourly changes.

What's wrong with using this solution for more frequent updates?

How should I go about implementing a lookup table sideinput that updates hourly?

Comment: Hourly vs daily should not be big trouble. This solution should work fine for hourly updates. As a question: How much data, approximately, will there be in your side input?  Are we talking TBs? 10s of GBs? Something else?

Comment: @Pablo much smaller than that, probably in the tens of megabytes maybe growing the hundreds. Why is it important?

Comment: It's only important if it may take a long time to load it in as a side input. If it's only a few 10s or 100s of megabytes, then it's completely fine to refresh them hourly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hourly vs daily should not represent a big difference for Dataflow. The solution should work well with hourly updates.

Consider the time it may take the engine (in this case Dataflow) to load in the side input. If you need to load TBs of data every hour, then that will likely be a problem for your pipeline.

On the other hand, if every hour you need to load MBs to few GBs of data, it should be relatively quick for your pipeline to do that every hour.

Comment: How should I approach this if the lookup tables are updated through (real-time) streaming as well? We are streaming data into two dimensional tables containing surrogate keys, and one fact table, all at the same time with three different dataflow jobs. We want to quickly retrieve the surrogate key from the dimensional tables to the fact table before insertion into BigQuery. I found an example here https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/guide-to-common-cloud-dataflow-use-case-patterns-part-2 , at the Pattern: Streaming mode large lookup tables section, can this help us in our cas